# Rails, Grape create custom JSON from collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, grape-api

I started to learn how to use Grape. I have collection with a lot of attributes and want only some of them. I did something like this:

```
get :all_elements do
    [
      my_collection.each do |element|
          {
           id: element.id,
           name: element.name
          }
      end
    ]
end
```

However this is not working. How can I create custom json array from collection?

Comment: Use grape entity - https://github.com/intridea/grape-entity for exposing specific attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
list = my_collection.map do |element|
           { :id => element.id,
             :name => element.email
           }
       end

list.to_json
```

Comment: It prints JSON with all attributes. I want only specific.

Comment: I am using map so it prints only specifics.